# Values of F and T (distribution tables) in Anova

Tags: probability-distributions, regression, linear-regression

I have to find the $p$-value but I'm having difficulty with the F values.

I have this table:

[image]

Now after some computation from an exercice, i calculate the F test statistic like so:

$F = \text{MSS}/\text{MSE}$,

- which in my case is $11.54/6.1506 = 1.8762$.
- The degree of freedom of my numerator is $1$ and of the denominator is
  $16$.
- How do I get my $p$-value from this table and this calculations? 
  Thanks you

Comment: Anyone please? would like to understand

Answer (score 1):

The last equation in your picture says: The $1-\alpha$-th quantile of an F distribution where the first parameter is one and the second is n (F($1-\alpha$, 1, n)) is the same as the square of the $1-\frac{\alpha}{2}$-th quantile of the t distribution with n degrees of freedom($t^2(1-\frac{\alpha}{2},n))$.

$\Rightarrow$  In theory this should work like this:

1.From the table of the t-distribution on the seventh row you read off the values for $\nu = 16$ and square them.

2. You use the equation $F(1-\alpha, 1, \nu) =t^2(1-\frac{\alpha}{2},\nu)$ to obtain the values of the quantile for $F(1-\alpha, 1, \nu)$:

For example: $t(0.900,16) = 1.34061 \hspace{.1cm} \Rightarrow t^2(0.900,16) = 1.797235$. Here $1-\frac{\alpha}{2} = 0.900 \hspace{.1cm} \Rightarrow \alpha = 0.2$ That means that $F(1-\alpha, 1, 16) = F(1-0.2, 1, 16) = F(0.8, 1, 16) = t^2(0.900,16) = 1.797235$.

***NOTE***: There is a ***mistake*** in the table - the row for $\nu = 16$ corresponds to the t-distribution with ***15 instead of 16*** degrees of freedom.

Ive seen this by checking with R:

```
> halfAlphas <- c(0.1, 0.05, 0.025, 0.015, 0.0125, 0.01, 0.005)
> qt(1-halfAlphas, 15)
[1] 1.340606 1.753050 2.131450 2.397005 2.489880 2.602480 2.946713
```

The remaining rows are OK:

```
outMatrix <- vapply(c(2:5, 10,20, 30, 40, 60, 120), function(elt) qt(1-halfAlphas, elt), numeric(length(halfAlphas)))
> rownames(outMatrix) <- 1-halfAlphas
> colnames(outMatrix) <- paste("n = ",c(2:5,10,20, 30, 40, 60, 120))
> t(outMatrix)
              0.9     0.95    0.975    0.985   0.9875     0.99    0.995
n =  2   1.885618 2.919986 4.302653 5.642778 6.205347 6.964557 9.924843
n =  3   1.637744 2.353363 3.182446 3.896046 4.176535 4.540703 5.840909
n =  4   1.533206 2.131847 2.776445 3.297630 3.495406 3.746947 4.604095
n =  5   1.475884 2.015048 2.570582 3.002875 3.163381 3.364930 4.032143
n =  10  1.372184 1.812461 2.228139 2.527484 2.633767 2.763769 3.169273
n =  20  1.325341 1.724718 2.085963 2.336242 2.423117 2.527977 2.845340
n =  30  1.310415 1.697261 2.042272 2.278262 2.359562 2.457262 2.749996
n =  40  1.303077 1.683851 2.021075 2.250271 2.328935 2.423257 2.704459
n =  60  1.295821 1.670649 2.000298 2.222923 2.299046 2.390119 2.660283
n =  120 1.288646 1.657651 1.979930 2.196202 2.269875 2.357825 2.617421
```

The quantiles of the t-distribution with 16 degrees of freedom are:

```
> t16 = qt(1-halfAlphas, 16)
> names(t16) <- 1- halfAlphas
> t16
     0.9     0.95    0.975    0.985   0.9875     0.99    0.995 
1.336757 1.745884 2.119905 2.381545 2.472878 2.583487 2.920782
```

The quantile values of $t^2(1-\frac{\alpha}{2},16)$ and $F(1-\alpha, 1, 16)$  are:

```
> outF1_16 <- rbind(qt(1-halfAlphas, 16)^2, qf(1-2*halfAlphas, 1, 16))
> colnames(outF1_16) <- 1-2*halfAlphas
> rownames(outF1_16) <- c("t(16)squared", "F(1,16)") 
> outF1_16
                 0.8     0.9     0.95     0.97    0.975     0.98     0.99
t(16)squared 1.78692 3.04811 4.493998 5.671758 6.115127 6.674406 8.530965
F(1,16)      1.78692 3.04811 4.493998 5.671758 6.115127 6.674406 8.530965
```

Your observation was 1.8762. This falls between the 80-th quantile (1.78692) and the 90-th quantile (3.04811) of the $F_{1,16}$ distribution. This means that your p-value is between 0.10 and 0.20.